# How do I set FQDN on Ubuntu 10.04 for Apache to recognize it

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, apache-http-server

/etc/hosts:

```
10.0.11.162 mpcore.bts.md mpcore
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1 mpcore  localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.11.162
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.11.0
broadcast 10.0.11.255
gateway 10.0.11.1
```

So, when I use IP http://10.0.11.162 I get the index.html

But when I use http://mpcore.bts.md I get "Server Not found" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server configuration is fine. The problem is that ***mpcore.bts.md* simply does not exist,** neither in DNS nor the hosts file.

Remember that your server's `/etc/hosts` only applies to programs running on that server. If you are trying to connect from a different computer, it *cannot* see the server's `hosts` file, only its own.

Comment: ok i was able to see the Virtual host from console (localhost) but not from outside :
i have ESXi installed on 10.0.11.11

DNS = 10.0.11.1, and 10.0.1.1


Installed an Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit VM on this ESXi with IP = 10.0.11.162 , dns = mpcore.example.com


Installed apache2 on 10.0.11.162


Configured virtual host "qa.mpcore.com"


This is Visible via a browser on the ubuntu console , but not from another computer outside the ESXi Environment


Any idea how to resolve this ?


Thanks,

Comment: @kamal: Add the `mpcore` subdomain to the DNS servers of `bts.md`. The primary server is `ns.ultra.md`, start with that.